# CSS dropdown navigation to open on clicking

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a CSS dropdown. But the problem is that my dropdown appears when I hover the mouse over the menu. But I want the dropdown to open when the user clicks at the menu. I cannot frame the jQuery code for the same. Please help me in this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add whatever code you have so we can better help you

Comment: please show us the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/06/simple-drop-down-menu-with-jquery-and.html) may help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function()
 {

 $(".account").click(function()
 {
var X=$(this).attr('id');
if(X==1)
 {
 $(".submenu").hide();
$(this).attr('id', '0'); 
 }
else
 {
 $(".submenu").show();
$(this).attr('id', '1');
 }

 });

//Mouse click on sub menu
 $(".submenu").mouseup(function()
 {
return false
 });

//Mouse click on my account link
 $(".account").mouseup(function()
     {
return false
 });


//Document Click
 $(document).mouseup(function()
 {
 $(".submenu").hide();
 $(".account").attr('id', '');
 });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: [Google also can help him a lot](http://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&biw=1024&bih=464&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery%20dropdown%20menu&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.aGc&fp=8d7a2d6407bc7dbc&pf=p&pdl=300)

Answer (score 1):

you can combine :active and :hover pseudo-selectors to make this in pure css,

HTML (note that tab name is below content):

```
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="content">Content 1</div>
  <div>Tab 1</div>
</div>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  <div>Tab 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs {
  float: left; /* place tabs in one line */
  margin: 10px; /* set margin between tabs */
}
.content {
  display: none; /* hide contents */
  padding-top: 20px; /* content must be below tab */
  position: absolute; /* fix content position */
}
.tabs:active .content {
  display: block; /* open content when clicking*/
}
.content:hover {
  display: block; /* not closing content while cursor is over it */
}
```

check the example: http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/JJj3G/

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your code a generic example:

```
jQuery(".Menu").click(function() { //Select menu by its class name or id

    //Select the part of the menu that is shown/hidden 
    //and animate it opening/closing
    jQuery(".DropMenuClassName").animate({height:'toggle'},600);
    //OR
    jQuery(".DropMenuClassName").slideToggle(600);
    //OR
    jQuery(".DropMenuClassName").css({display:"none"});

});
```